# Grails - Passing domain parameter to Javascript

Tags: ajax, grails

Is there a way to pass an instance variable in my gsp file to Javascript?

This is what I have that doesn't work:

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addTo('${person.id}');" />
```

${person.id} is the ID of the domain instance Person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works just fine for me. I'm able to send an id to a javascript function and show it in an alert. Are you getting an error, or is the value just not being passed?  Maybe add your javascript to the question.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Instead of passing the value directly through the button, I just reference that id value in the javascript function data array directly. Works for me in my current set up.